# Repeating/Stuttering 'For' Loop in PHP

Tags: php, loops, debugging, for-loop

The 'for' loop in my code repeats the execution of the first pass through the code multiple times before moving onto the next pass. The loop should repeat 3 times, but the script is executed multiple times on the first repetition. I realized this when I saw the following in the error log:

> [24-Jul-2017 15:03:42 America/New_York] Sent to: *
>  [24-Jul-2017
>   15:03:42 America/New_York] 1
>  [24-Jul-2017 15:03:48
>   America/New_York] Sent to: *
>  [24-Jul-2017 15:03:49
>   America/New_York] 1
>  [24-Jul-2017 15:03:55 America/New_York] Sent
>   to: *
>  [24-Jul-2017 15:03:55 America/New_York] 1
>  [24-Jul-2017
>   15:04:01 America/New_York] Sent to: *
>  [24-Jul-2017 15:04:01
>   America/New_York] 1
>  [24-Jul-2017 15:04:07 America/New_York] Sent
>   to: *
>  [24-Jul-2017 15:04:08 America/New_York] 1
>  [24-Jul-2017
>   15:04:14 America/New_York] Sent to: *
>  [24-Jul-2017 15:04:14
>   America/New_York] 1
>  [24-Jul-2017 15:04:20 America/New_York] Sent
>   to: *
>  [24-Jul-2017 15:04:20 America/New_York] 1
>  [24-Jul-2017
>   15:04:26 America/New_York] Sent to: *
>  [24-Jul-2017 15:04:26
>   America/New_York] 1
>  [24-Jul-2017 15:04:32 America/New_York] No
>   message received!
>  [24-Jul-2017 15:04:32 America/New_York] 2
>   [24-Jul-2017 15:04:38 America/New_York] No message received!
>   [24-Jul-2017 15:04:38 America/New_York] 3

I had it write the loop count to the log at the end of each loop, and you can see that the first is repeated more than once. Here is the code relevant to my loop:

```
for ($count = 0; $count < 4; $count++) {

// Do STUFF HERE
// ERROR_LOG when a successful message has been sent

error_log($count);
sleep(5);
}
```

I have no idea why this is happening since the code looks okay to me. Could it be a server issue? Or perhaps something in the rest of the code is affecting the loop? How do I get it to loop the correct amount of times?

In case it could be of use, this is the full code I am using. It basically just forwards email attachments to a group of email addresses found in an SQL database.

```
// INCLUDE FUNCTIONS FOR OPENING EMAIL ATTACHMENT

include('attach.php');

// OPEN EMAIL AND CHECK FOR ATTACHMENT

for ($count = 0; $count < 4; $count++) {


/* connect to gmail */
$hostname = '***';
$username = '***';
$password = '***';
/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

$max_emails = 16;


/* if any emails found, iterate through each email */
if($emails) {

    $count = 1;

    /* put the newest emails on top */
    rsort($emails);

    /* for every email... */
    foreach($emails as $email_number) 
    {

        /* get information specific to this email */
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);

        /* grab sender's phone number */
        foreach ($overview as $msgparts){
        $fromaddress = $msgparts->from;
        $fromnumber = explode("@", $fromaddress);
        $sendernumber = substr($fromnumber[0], -10);    
        }

    /* check if sender's number is in the database */   
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "***";
$password = "***";
$dbname = "***";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   error_log("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    goto end;
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Members WHERE Phone_Number LIKE '$sendernumber'";
$result = $conn->query($sql); 

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {    
$conn->close();
   error_log("Member number (" . $sendernumber . ") not recognized!");
    goto end;
}  else {
      $conn->close();
} 
} 

        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

        /* get mail structure */
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $email_number);

        $attachments = array();

        /* if any attachments found... */
        if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) 
        {
            for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) 
            {
                $attachments[$i] = array(
                    'is_attachment' => false,
                    'filename' => '',
                    'name' => '',
                    'attachment' => ''
                );

                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters) 
                {
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) 
                    {
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') 
                        {
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                            $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters) 
                {
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) 
                    {
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') 
                        {
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                            $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment']) 
                {
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, $i+1);

                    /* 3 = BASE64 encoding */
                    if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3) 
                    { 
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                    }
                    /* 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE encoding */
                    elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4) 
                    { 
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /* iterate through each attachment and save it */
        foreach($attachments as $attachment)
        {
            if($attachment['is_attachment'] == 1)
            {
                //error_log($attachment['name']);
                //error_log($attachment['attachment']);
                $filetype = substr($attachment['name'], -3);
                //$filename = $attachment['name'];
                if ( ($filetype == "txt") || ($attachment['name'] == "")) {
                $filename = "message.txt";
                if(empty($filename)) $filename = $attachment['filename'];

                if(empty($filename)) $filename = time() . ".dat";

                /* prefix the email number to the filename in case two emails
                 * have the attachment with the same file name.
                 */
                //$fp = fopen("./" . $email_number . "-" . $filename, "w+");
                $fp = fopen("./message.txt", "w+");
                fwrite($fp, $attachment['attachment']);
                fclose($fp);
                    }
                    else { 
                    //not a text message
                    }
           }
    }
}


// EXTRACT EMAIL ATTACHMENT TO TEXT FILE

If (file_exists("message.txt")) {

$emailmessage = fopen("message.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$relaymessage = fread($emailmessage,filesize("message.txt"));
fclose($emailmessage);
unlink ("message.txt");
} else {
    error_log("No message received!");
    goto end;
}

// FORWARD ATTACHMENT TO ALL USERS IN DATABASE

If ($relaymessage != "") {

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "***";
$password = "***";
$dbname = "***";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    //die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   error_log("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    goto end;
} 

$sql = "SELECT Address FROM Members";
$result = $conn->query($sql); 

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {    
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
        $sent=normal($row["Address"], $relaymessage, "", 1);
        error_log("Sent to: " . $row["Address"]);
}
}  else {
      error_log("Error: " . $row["Address"]);
}

$conn->close();

} else {
    error_log("Message is blank");
    goto end;
}

end:
imap_delete($inbox,$email_number);
imap_expunge($inbox);
imap_close($inbox), CL_EXPUNGE);
error_log($count);
sleep(5);
}


function normal($to,$message,$oper,$num)
{
$adhead="";
for($i=1;$i<=$num;$i++)
{
$sent=mail($to, "", $message, $adhead);
}
if($sent)
{
echo "<h1>Mail sent successfully to $to</h1>";
}
else
{
echo '<h1>Mail not sent!</h1>';
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem here :

```
if($emails) {    $count = 1;//<======
```

`$count` is used in the `for` loop, but it's edited in the insider `if`!

So you have to use another variable name.